# how to modify .csproj file using xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

my csproj file contain below itemgroup.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

i wanted to replace

```
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" /> //it have little bit space between Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" and closing tag(/>)
To    
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"/> //it have no space.
```

i don't want any space.how to achive it using  XDocument linq.

Comment: my code is breaking if it conation space.so that i wanted no space inside of it

Comment: What you are doing by read *.csproj? And it is a wellformed XML.

Comment: `<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />` is legal XML - the space doesn't matter.  What message are you getting when you try to compile?

Comment: If you've got code or a component that claims to deal with xml, and it breaks when you give it xml, the thing to do isn't to change what you pass it, but to **fix that code or component**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't know why you would need to read a .csproj file for anything, but you can do a couple of things.

- You can just open up the file in NotePad and edit the space(s) out.
- If Visual Studio puts the spaces back in, then maybe you can take the space out again and use a closing tag.

  `<ItemGroup>`
  `<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"></Compile>`
  `</ItemGroup>`

Maybe I just don't get the question.